Should I delete questions like that?

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: If $G$ is a simple non-abelian group, what can we say about its proper subgroups?
I wrote this question but an user pointed out that:

my proof is incorrect
the statement is false

So, I believe there is no way this question could be useful to others.
Should I delete it?

If it has no lasting value to others, then yes, deleting it might be appropriate.  Ultimately, that is your decision: it's not my place to force you to delete your own question.
I discourage "please check whether my proof is correct" questions, because often their answers aren't very helpful (they tend to be just "yes" or "no").  More importantly, because it's unlikely anyone else will ever have exactly the same question in the future (and if they did, it's unlikely they could find it via search).  So such questions have little value for the future.
A key part of our mission is to build a library of knowledge, an archive of information that will be useful to others in the future, using questions and answers as a format and a means towards that end.  So if you're asking a question that is unlikely to be useful to others -- whether because it is based on a faulty premise, or because it is so narrow and specific that it's unlikely to arise for anyone else, or because it would be too hard for anyone else with the same question to find it -- then such a question isn't well suited to our mission.  I encourage you to try to guide your activity towards questions that are aligned with our mission.
